# LOGIN test with JMeter

Tags: web-applications, jmeter, oracle-apex

I have to do performance testing of Oracle APEX based web application. I'm unable to login with JMeter in application and because of that testing can not go ahead. I've done recording with blazemeter extension.

Comment: Provide more information such as error, log and your test plan.

Comment: All test are going green but result are not expected. Web application has dual log in page but after running test response data screen is showing same log in page. And no audit log created in the website. In database it shows current active sessions are increasing on homepage but no parameter passed.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to APEX applications load testing you will not be able to record and replay as you will need to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) of the following parameters:

- `p_instance`
- `p_flow_id`
- `p_flow_step_id`
- `p_page_submission_id`
- `p_md5_checksum`
- `p_arg_names`

You need to extract them from the previous response using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and replace recorded hard-coded values with the relevant [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan